# How to execute a batch file on a remote system

Tags: java, .net, windows, batch-file, client-server

I have a java web app running on a server. I will click a button on the UI on the server It should invoke the batch file on the client machine and execute it on the client. Please suggest me how to go on doing it?

Comment: Metasploit, maybe? (I kid, I kid.)

Comment: could you please share the reason for the down vote? May be I can improve the question.

Comment: what action do you want to perform through batch file

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a web app and it involves a browser as a client, then you cannot invoke a script on every client machine (I mean, you can do it in Windows, but not Linux).
Javascript is a client scripting language and runs in a sand-boxed environment often inside a web browser which prevents it from accessing resources on the computer.
Nevertheless in Windows, you probably could do this:

```
var cmdshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
cmdshell.Run("the command to run a batch script goes here");
```

Check [this](http://www.itjungle.com/mpo/mpo052302-story01.html) for more details.

But in Linux, I haven't seen a way to do it since the environment is different altogether.